# What's this camera view of Falcon Heavy's test flight?

Tags: falcon-heavy, identify-this-object

At about T+1:51, the lower left tile switches to some camera view I don't understand. But only for the fraction of a second, then view is back to normal.

Video at that position:

Snapshot of that particular moment:

[image: what's the lower left vies?]

Answer (score 2):

My guess? Its the top of the second stage engine.  Unusual place for a camera, maybe they have monitoring cameras everywhere so that if something untoward happens they can resurrect the footage and glean some answers?  But it looks a lot to me like engine bay electronics - whether its first or second stage is the real question.

Comment: There is an answer or a comment here somewhere that mentions an estimate of the total number of cameras on and in a F9. I think it's like fifty or sixty, but I can't find it yet. I expected it to be near the question [Roughly how many self-viewing cameras are present in a Falcon 9 LEO mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19891/12102) but it's not there now.

Comment: Why do you guess that it's an engine's top? Are there any other pictures of such a part? Or sketches or animations?

Answer (score 0):

It’s interesting how mundane that looks. The wiring is loosely held; not something I’d have expected for a high-G rocket. And you can see a couple of low-pressure actuators that would be at home in anybody’s car.

I wonder if it’s an internal view of some space in The Roadster.  Maybe to check that nothing is shaking loose?